# Firebase web app Chat duplicates chat input

Tags: jquery, firebase

Hi I'm new to firebase and was trying to develop a chat app everything looks ok for the processing of the chat message except that it duplicates the data on the sender's panel as soon as a user switch to pm a different user and after he/she goes back to the previous user it also duplicates the chat for that person too.. although it doesn't store on the firebase database which is also weird.. the duplicate starts from 1 then after that it increments if the user switches to other user/s again

Here is the whole firebase code for the chat app this is the combination of presence and the chat tutorial I just did a small modification on it and I dont know which of the script is causing this duplicate

```
   // Reference for tbl message
  var messagesRef = new Firebase('https://url-for-tablemessage');


  // Reference for tbl userprofile
  var userListRef = new Firebase("https://url-for-userprofile");


  var myUser = userListRef.child(idf);
  // Get a reference to my own presence status.
  var connectedRef = new Firebase("https://url-for-userprofile//.info/connected");

 function getmsg(){
            // Loads Previous Message with the selected user/s.
     messageList.html("");
     messagesRef.limit(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
           //GET DATA
           var data = snapshot.val(), username = data.name, message = data.text,
               sendr = data.sender, recievr = data.reciever, ui =  $('#chat-avatar').attr("data-ui"),
               style_c = "";

 if (username != nameField){ style_c = "message chat";}
             else{ style_c = "message user";  }

                    var messageElement = $('<div class="'+style_c+'"><div class="message-info">'+
             '<img width="40" height="40" src="temp/user/'+username+'.jpg">' +
                 '<div class="message-timestamp">' +
                 ' <time datetime="" class="timeago uk-text-small">09:22 am</time>' +
                 '</div></div>' +
               ' <div class="message-data">' +
               ' <div class="bubble"></div></div></div>');
         if (((idf == sendr) && (ui == recievr) )||((idf == recievr) && (ui == sendr) )){
               messageElement.find('.bubble').html(message).emoji();
               //ADD MESSAGE

               messageList.append(messageElement);}
           //SCROLL TO BOTTOM OF MESSAGE LIST
              messageList[0].scrollTop = messageList[0].scrollHeight;
   });
  }
  // A helper function to let us set our own state.
  function setUserStatus(status) {
    // Set our status in the list of online users.
    currentStatus = status;
    myUser.set({ id:idf, names: name, firstname:fname, lastname:lname, status: status });
  }
  function getMessageId(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.name().replace(/[^a-z0-9\-\_]/gi,'');
  }
  // Update our GUI to show someone"s online status.
  userListRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot.val();

  if (user.names != name) {
         $("<a />")
        .attr({"id": getMessageId(snapshot),"data-username":user.names,"data-fname":user.firstname,"data-lname":user.lastname})
        .html(user.names + "<br />")
        .appendTo("#presenceDiv")
        .click(function(){
           var dt = $(this).attr("data-username"),df=$(this).attr("data-fname"),dl=$(this).attr("data-lname"),
               src="temp/user/"+dt+".jpg";
               $('#chat-avatar').show();
           $('#chat-avatar').attr({'src':src,"data-os":user.status,"data-ui":user.id})
           $('#chat-name').html(df + " " + dl);
           console.log(dt);
         messageList.html(""); 
         getmsg();
    });
        $("<li />")
        .attr({"id": getMessageId(snapshot),"data-username":user.names,"class":"offcanvas-chat-avatar","data-fname":user.firstname,"data-lname":user.lastname})
        .html("<small id='ofstat' data-os="+user.status+" data-ui="+user.id+" ></small><img width='40' height='40' src='temp/user/"+user.names+".jpg'>"+ user.names )
        .appendTo("#clist")
        .click(function(){
                  var dt = $(this).attr("data-username"),df=$(this).attr("data-fname"),dl=$(this).attr("data-lname"),
               src="temp/user/"+dt+".jpg";
                  $('#chat-avatar').show();
           $('#chat-avatar').attr({'src':src,"data-os":user.status,"data-ui":user.id});
           $('#chat-name').html(df + " " + dl);
           console.log(dt);
           messageList.html(""); 
           getmsg();

    });


    }

  });




  // LISTEN FOR KEYPRESS EVENT
  messageField.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      //FIELD VALUES
  //messageList.html(""); 
      var username = nameField;
      var message = messageField.val();
      var ui =  $('#chat-avatar').attr("data-ui");
  if(message != ""){
      //SAVE DATA TO FIREBASE AND EMPTY FIELD

      messagesRef.push({name:username, text:message, sender:idf, reciever:ui});

      }else{
      alert("Text Field Empty");
      }
      //getmsg();

      messageField.val('');

      e.preventDefault();
      // return false;
    } 
  });
```

I really need this to get on working.. been stuck here for almost 3weeks now I'm not sure if what I'm doing is actually correct because of this but what I can say is that I think the error lies on the getmsg() function not sure though... Please help me :(

Comment: hi there! I'm not seeing a lot of due diligence here. Could you try to isolate the problem a bit and clean up your example? For instance: userListRef and messagesRef point to the same URL; much of this code appears superfluous; reducing it to the offending algorithm will likely resolve the issue. You are the best person to debug your code; produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get the most accurate and insightful answers.

Comment: hi @Kato the reason why I changed the userListRef and messagesRef's url into http://url is because the real url behind it contains the actual access to my firebase account that is why I used "url" instead although I have to agree with you that it was wrong to vaguely use url alone I'll just have to update it and clean up the comments remove unnecessary codes that are likely involve in my current question after this comment..

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to format the messages differently when they're from the currently authenticated user? Is that why getMsg() is being called?

I'll offer you another way of thinking about it, as it's something I've managed to do, and I don't have this error. I think your error is coming form the fact that .on('child_added') might be called regardless of whether you call getMsg() or not.

My solution involves the following

```
messagesRef.limit(msgLimit).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();

        //format timestamp from linux epoch to readable format
        var ts = getTimestamp(message.timestamp);

        //gets the image from the user who sent the message
        var userImg = userSnapshot.child(message.userID).child('img').val();

        //variables for message layout
        var chatMsgImg = $('<img>',{class:'avatar', src:userImg});
        var chatMsgDiv = $('<div/>',{class:'message'});
        var chatMsgArrow = $('<span/>', {class:'arrow'});
        var chatMsgName = $('<span/>', {class:'name'}).text(message.from);
        var chatMsgTimestamp = $('<span/>', {class:'datetime'}).text(' '+ts);
        var chatMsgContent = $('<span/>', {class:'body'}).text(message.text);

        //if the message is from the currently signed in user, then align right and use class out
        if((message.userID) == userID){
            var msg = $('<li/>', {class:'out'});
            msg.append(chatMsgImg);
            chatMsgDiv.append(chatMsgArrow);
            chatMsgDiv.append(chatMsgName);
            chatMsgDiv.append(chatMsgTimestamp);
            chatMsgDiv.append(chatMsgContent);
            msg.append(chatMsgDiv);
            msg.appendTo($('#chatDiv'));
        }
        //otherwise align left and use class in
        else{
            var msg = $('<li/>', {class:'in'});
            msg.append(chatMsgImg);
            chatMsgDiv.append(chatMsgArrow);
            chatMsgDiv.append(chatMsgName);
            chatMsgDiv.append(chatMsgTimestamp);
            chatMsgDiv.append(chatMsgContent);
            msg.append(chatMsgDiv);
            msg.appendTo($('#chatDiv'));
        }

        $('#chatDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#chatDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
    });
```

By doing it this way, I still get the message details just the same, but I leave the formatting up to CSS simply using in and out or incoming and outgoing messages (from other users, and from the current user, respectively)

Comment: the reason getmsg() is being called is for loading the msg based on the user that was chosen by the sender. How is it possible that the .on('child_added') is being called wherein on my script its only on the getmsg() function ??

Comment: sorry tried your code and the result is still the same

Comment: Ah ok. So you want some way to filter the data results?

Comment: yea I just want to get rid of the duplicating issue after sending to a different user to another ;(

Comment: You might want to look at changing your data structure if this is the case :/ If you're used to traditional database architecture then you should look at Firebase in a very different way, since the structure of the data is very different

Comment: Yeah I guess I could do that this thing is totally new to me